# Get data from one array into another using reduce

Tags: jquery

I have this script which groups data (commit messages) by date.

I would like to add a link to each message with the individual sha.

How do I include this data from the first `data` object into the `newData` object so that I end up with a variable sort of like this: `var commitUrl = gitHubUrl + sha;` which can be added to each `href`?

The script:

```
function fetchDatafromGitHub() {
  var user = "google";
  var repo = "coding-with-chrome"
  var gitHubUrl = "https://github.com/" + user + "/" + repo + "/commit/";
  var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + user + "/" + repo + "/commits";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var newData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        var date = el.commit.committer.date;
        var msg = el.commit.message;
        var sha = el.sha;
        console.log(sha);
        var d = date.split('T')[0];
        if (acc.hasOwnProperty(d))
          acc[d].push(msg);
        else
          acc[d] = [msg];
        return acc;
      }, {})
      Object.keys(newData).forEach(function(v, k) {
        //console.log(newData);
        var date = v;
        var message = newData[v].join(", ");
        var t = new Date(date);
        var day = ("0" + (
          t.getDate())).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (
          t.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var year = t.getFullYear();
        //var commitUrl = gitHubUrl + sha;

        gitHubStats.append('<div>' + day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ': <a href="#" target="_blank">' + message + '</a></div>');
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ekLfLt/1/).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible way, check one of this solution.

Here i passed message with href set with commitUrl in newData object. And just appended in final message.  Hope it helps

```js
var gitHubStats = $('body');

function fetchDatafromGitHub() {
  var user = "google";
  var repo = "coding-with-chrome"
  var gitHubUrl = "https://github.com/" + user + "/" + repo + "/commit/";
  var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + user + "/" + repo + "/commits";
  var maxHits = 5;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      var newData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        var date = el.commit.committer.date;
        var msg = el.commit.message;
        var sha = el.sha;
        var d = date.split('T')[0];
        
        var commitUrl = gitHubUrl + sha;
        
        var temp_message = '<a href="' + commitUrl + '" target="_blank">' + msg + '</a>';
        
        if (acc.hasOwnProperty(d))
          acc[d].push(temp_message);
        else
          acc[d] = [temp_message];
        return acc;
      }, {})
      
      Object.keys(newData).forEach(function(v, k) {
        var date = v;
        //var message = newData[v].join(", ");
        var t = new Date(date);
        var day = ("0" + (
          t.getDate())).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (
          t.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var year = t.getFullYear();
        //var commitUrl = gitHubUrl + sha;
        
        gitHubStats.append('<div>' + day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ': ' + newData[v] + '</div>');
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
fetchDatafromGitHub();
```

```css
div+div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wait, Sorry just found there is a issue you can see href not setting properly.

Comment: Ok, what is the fix?